# Add string before and after array values for php>mysql searching

Tags: php, mysql, regex

I have an html form with multiple checkboxes. I pass those to php...

The values will come in like "G,BW" for example ("BW,G" needs to match as well)
in check.php, I need to take the values from $_GET and modify them for an sql query...

```
<?php
if(!empty($_GET['wireColor'])) {
    foreach($_GET['wireColor'] as $colors) {
    echo $colors; //make sure it's right, then comment out
    }
}

$colors = rtrim($colors, ','); //Get rid of trailing , - not working right

$wireSearch = '\'REGEXP \'.*(^|,).$wireColor.(,|$)\''; //Trying to add the sql bits to pass to the query.
```

Ideally to get this passed:

```
$colors_lookup_sql = "SELECT * FROM parts WHERE ( wire_colors REGEXP '.*(^|,)$wireSearch(,|$)' and wire_colors REGEXP '.*(^|,)$wireSearch(,|$)' );";
```

Here's how the query should look at the end:

```
SELECT * FROM parts WHERE ( wire_colors REGEXP '.*(^|,)G(,|$)' and wire_colors REGEXP '.*(^|,)BW(,|$)' );
```

I'm having a hard time getting the regex bits into the query.

**UPDATE**

Here's what I have now:

```
<?php
if(!empty($_GET['wireColor'])) {
    foreach($_GET['wireColor'] as $colors) {
        $wireSearch = ' REGEXP \'.*(^|,)' .$colors.'(,|$)\' AND ';
    }
}

$Search = rtrim($wireSearch, 'AND'); //Trying to trim the last "AND"
$colors_lookup_sql = "SELECT * FROM parts WHERE ( wire_colors $wireSearch% );";
```

Which gives me mostly what I need, but print/echo the results and I get:

$wireSearch ends up as: `REGEXP '.*(^|,)G(,|$)' AND REGEXP '.*(^|,)BW(,|$)' AND` Which is great - I just need to nuke the last "AND". The trim above replaces it with the second value instead though. Weird.

and $colors_lookup_sql ends up as: `SELECT * FROM parts WHERE ( wire_colors REGEXP '.*(^|,)BW(,|$)' AND % );`

BUt for some reason the first value in the array goes away, which I don't understand since it was present before the sql statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about the REGEX inside the query since I haven't used it but:

```
$wireSearch = '\'REGEXP \'.*(^|,).$wireColor.(,|$)\'';
```

Here you have a problem, the variable `$wireColor` is inside a string, and you are using `'` so anything inside is not read as a variable, it should be something like:

```
$wireSearch = '\'REGEXP \'.*(^|,)'.$wireColor.'(,|$)\'';
```

Comment: That's why I was escaping them - I'll give that a shot.

Comment: This worked well enough to get me a lot further.. See my updates.

Comment: I'm gonna call this one solved - even though it led me down a rabbit hole. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I cant say I entirely understand how your data is being stored, and I havent worked with REGEX much myself, but perhaps something like this would be a bit easier to work with:

```
$wireSearch = explode(",", $_GET['wireColor']);
$query = "SELECT * FROM parts WHERE wire_colors LIKE '%$wireSearch[0]%' 
         AND wire_colors LIKE '%$wireSearch[1]%'";
```

Not sure if this helps but I thought id throw in the idea.

Answer (score 0):

I guess mysql regex supports word boundaries, how about:

```
wire_colors REGEX '\bBW\b' and wire_colors regex '\bW\b'
```